# Recursive function fails depending on lexical scoping

Tags: python, recursion, lexical-scope

I want to generate variations on a name by edit distance equal or smaller than a number. I thought the simplest solution was a recursion. If I add the results of the current step after the recursion, the following code works fine; if I add them before, the recursion fails to terminate:

```py
def generate_distance1(name):

    res = []
    
    # Deletion.
    for i in range(len(name)):
        if 0 == i:
            res.append(name[1:])
        elif len(name) - 1 == i:
            res.append(name[:-1])
        else:
            res.append(name[:i] + name[i+1:])

    # Substitution.
    for i in range(len(name)):
        if 0 == i:
            res.append("?" + name[1:])
        elif len(name) - 1 == i:
            res.append(name[:-1] + "?")
        else:
            res.append(name[:i] + "?" + name[i+1:])

    # Addition
    for i in range(len(name) + 1):
        if 0 == i:
            res.append("?" + name)
        elif len(name) == i:
            res.append(name + "?")
        else:
            res.append(name[:i] + "?" + name[i:])

    res = list(set(res))
    
    return res


def generate_distance(name, max_distance, before):
    if 0 == max_distance:
        return [name]

    dist1 = generate_distance1(name)
    if 1 == max_distance:
        return dist1

    if before:
        # This is not OK.
        res = dist1
    else:
        # This is OK.
        res = []

    for n in dist1:
        res.extend(generate_distance(n, max_distance - 1, before))

    if not before:
        res.extend(dist1)
        
    return list(set(res))

print(generate_distance("abracadabra", 2, before=False))

print(generate_distance("abracadabra", 2, before=True))
```

I'm using Python 3.11.6. I think this issue has to do with lexical scoping, and possibly closures, but I cannot understand why; neither can I really formulate a better title for the question. Why does this recursive function fail to terminate?

Comment: `res = dist1` doesn't copy `dist1`.  It just makes `res` an alias for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the *before* version is that the `for` loop will extend the list that is being iterated:

```
    for n in dist1:
        res.extend(generate_distance(n, max_distance - 1, before))
```

As you had made `res` identical to `dist1`, the above code really is doing this:

```
    for n in dist1:
        dist1.extend(generate_distance(n, max_distance - 1, before))
```

The loop should not have to iterate over more items than `dist1` originally head, and as `generate_distance` will always produce a non-empty list, this loop never ends (until a memory limit is hit).

This fix of the *before* approach is to create a new list for `res` (like you also create a new list in the *after* approach):

```
res = dist1[:]
```

Unrelated to your question, but in `generate_distance1` you don't need to have `if ... elif ... else` blocks. You can apply the generic slicing (in the `else` case) also to the two first cases. This is true for the deletion, the update and insert cases.

Comment: Thanks for both tips! The second one made me realize a bug I had and that I had missed quite a few variations, so thank you for that, very helpful!